# "Trace/BPT trap: 5" error with MacPorts and Brew

Tags: homebrew, osx-mavericks, macports

I need to use gnuplot and a bunch of other stuff, so I installed MacPorts and Brew on Mavericks. After installing the packages, if I try to plot something I get the `Trace/BPT trap: 5` error. Reinstalling XQuartz didn't fix the problem. Do you know how could I fix this? I tried various methods suggested online but nothing worked. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you install gnu plot and what command line?

Comment: Hi @Mark, at the end I uninstalled MacPorts and switched to [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). After you install Homebrew, you should check that everything is fine (`brew doctor`) and then update (`brew update`). You can then install gnuplot simply by typing `brew install gnuplot`. With MacPorts, the command to install gnuplot is `sudo port install gnuplot`.

Comment: By the way, I still have the `Trace/BPT trap: 5` error.

Comment: port info gnu plot gives a lust of variants which one did you use - default is -x11 so XQuartz is not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Homebrew, the solution is simply `brew uninstall gnuplot && brew install gnuplot --with-x`.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar problem: "kdiff3", which had been working fine for months, suddenly started dying with a similar message.  "mistym" on the "#machomebrew" IRC channel on freenode suggested that I uninstall qt and reinstall; I did; I then uninstalled and reinstalled kdiff3 and now it all works.